# linking assessments to students

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, erd

I am trying to create a student information database however there is a part that is continually confusing me.

A course has many assessments (mid-module exam, homework, final exam...etc) Each assessment has a name, weight and amount ( how much the student got out of the weight for example 30 out of 50). How do I link the student to the amount or Am I doing this wrong?

students -||---< enrolled_in_course >---||- course -||--< assessment

Comment: all you have is to add one additional table linked to student and assessment, this table will hold the weight of the student for the selected assessment

Comment: It's not homework. I'm trying learn database design by doing large project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

[image]

Note how COURSE_ID originates from COURSE, then propagates down both "edges" of the "diamond", only to be merged at the "bottom", in SCORE. This ensures a student cannot be scored on a course (s)he didn't enroll.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Branko. What program did you use to create that diagram?

Comment: @eforth Microsoft Visio, using template: Software and Database / Database Model Diagram.

Comment: I thought about a solution similar to this but I wasn't sure. You are correct in assuming that a student cannot be scored on a course he/she  wasn't enrolled in. My hope for this project is to turn it into a college information system and at the same time gain lots of experience. Thanks again for assistance Branko!

Answer (score 0):

students -||---< enrolled_in_course >---||- course

course -||--< assessment

students -||---< weight_in_assessment >---||- assessment